# Shogun / quadratic MMD error caused by varying train_test_ratio

Tags: python, shogun

I'm using Shogun to run MMD (quadratic) and compare two nonparametric distributions based on their samples (code below is for 1D, but I've also looked at 2D samples). In the toy problem shown below, I try to change the ratio between training and testing samples in the process of selecting an optimized kernel (KSM_MAXIMIZE_MMD is the selection strategy; I've also used KSM_MEDIAN_HEURISTIC). It appears that any ratio other than 1 yields an error.

Am I allowed to change this ratio in this setting?
(I see that it is used at: http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/examples/latest/examples/statistical_testing/quadratic_time_mmd.html, but it is set to 1 there)

---

Concise version of the my code (inspired by the notebook available at: http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/notebook/latest/mmd_two_sample_testing.html):

```
import shogun as sg
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import laplace, norm

n = 220
mu = 0.0
sigma2 = 1
b=np.sqrt(0.5)
X = sg.RealFeatures((norm.rvs(size=n) * np.sqrt(sigma2) + mu).reshape(1,-1))
Y = sg.RealFeatures(laplace.rvs(size=n, loc=mu, scale=b).reshape(1,-1))

mmd = sg.QuadraticTimeMMD(X, Y)
mmd.add_kernel(sg.GaussianKernel(10, 1.0))
mmd.set_kernel_selection_strategy(sg.KSM_MAXIMIZE_MMD)
mmd.set_train_test_mode(True)       
mmd.set_train_test_ratio(1)
mmd.select_kernel()

mmd_kernel = sg.GaussianKernel.obtain_from_generic(mmd.get_kernel())
kernel_width = mmd_kernel.get_width()
statistic = mmd.compute_statistic()
p_value = mmd.compute_p_value(statistic)

print p_value
```

This exact version runs and prints p-values just fine. 
If I change the argument passed to `mmd.set_train_test_ratio()` from 1 to 2, I get:

```
SystemErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-dd5fcb933287> in <module>()
     25 kernel_width = mmd_kernel.get_width()
     26 
---> 27 statistic = mmd.compute_statistic()
     28 p_value = mmd.compute_p_value(statistic)
     29 

SystemError: [ERROR] In file /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/shogun-cpp_1512688880429/work/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/src/shogun/statistical_testing/internals/mmd/ComputeMMD.h line 90: assertion kernel_matrix.num_rows==size && kernel_matrix.num_cols==size failed in float32_t shogun::internal::mmd::ComputeMMD::operator()(const shogun::SGMatrix<T>&) const [with T = float; float32_t = float] file /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/shogun-cpp_1512688880429/work/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/src/shogun/statistical_testing/internals/mmd/ComputeMMD.h line 90
```

It gets worse, if I use the value below 1. In addition to the following error,
jupyter notebook kernel crashes every time (after which I need to rerun the entire notebook; the message says: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.").

```
SystemErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-cb4a5224f4ef> in <module>()
     20 mmd.set_train_test_ratio(0.5)
     21 
---> 22 mmd.select_kernel()
     23 
     24 mmd_kernel = sg.GaussianKernel.obtain_from_generic(mmd.get_kernel())

SystemError: [ERROR] In file /feedstock_root/build_artefacts/shogun-cpp_1512688880429/work/shogun-shogun_6.1.3/src/shogun/kernel/Kernel.h line 210: GaussianKernel::kernel(): index out of Range: idx_a=146/146 idx_b=0/146
```

Complete code (in a jypyter notebook) can be found at: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/dmitry.duplyakin.org/p/jn/kernel-minimal.ipynb

Please let me know if I am missing a step or need to try a different approach.

---

Side questions:

- Both http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/examples/latest/examples/statistical_testing/quadratic_time_mmd.html and http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/notebook/latest/mmd_two_sample_testing.html show examples of using `sg.GaussianKernel(10, <width>)`. I couldn't find more information about the 1st parameter other than its name, cache size. How and when am I supposed to change it?
- As mentioned in the referenced notebook,  `mmd.get_kernel_selection_strategy().get_name()` returns only the generic name, specifically `KernelSelectionStrategy`. How can I obtain a more specific name for the selected strategy (e.g., `KSM_MEDIAN_HEURISTIC`) from an instance of the sg.QuadraticTimeMMD class?

Any relevant information or references will be greatly appreciated.

---

Shogun version: v6.1.3_2017-12-7_19:14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary (from comments):

- The bug does not show up in the latest code
- Solution is in: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/pull/4134

Answer (score 1):

- The `train_test_ratio` attribute is the ratio between the number of samples used in training and the number of samples used in testing. When you have `train_test_mode` turned on, the way it decides how many samples to fetch in each mode goes something like this.

  ```
  num_training_samples = m_num_samples * train_test_ratio / (train_test_ratio + 1)
  num_testing_samples  = m_num_samples / (train_test_ratio + 1)
  ```

  It implicitly assumes the divisibility. A `train_test_ratio` of 2 would, therefore, try to use 2/3rd of the data for training and 1/3rd of the data for testing, which is problematic for the total number of samples you have, 220. By the logic, it sets `num_training_samples` = 146 and `num_testing_samples` = 73, which doesn't add up to 220. Similar issues arise when using 0.5 as the train-test ratio. If you use some other values for the `train_test_ratio` which splits the total number of samples perfectly, I think these errors would go away.
- I am not totally sure but I think the cache makes sense when you're using SVMLight with Shogun. Please check http://svmlight.joachims.org/ for details. From their page

  ```
  -m [5..]    - size of cache for kernel evaluations in MB (default 40)
                The larger the faster...
  ```
- There's no pretty-print for the kernel-selection strategy being used, but you could do `mmd.get_kernel_selection_strategy().get_method()` which returns you the enum value (of type EKernelSelectionMethod) which might be helpful. Since it's not documented yet in Shogun api-doc, here's the C++ equivalent for this that you might use.

  ```
  enum EKernelSelectionMethod
  {
      KSM_MEDIAN_HEURISTIC,
      KSM_MAXIMIZE_MMD,
      KSM_MAXIMIZE_POWER,
      KSM_CROSS_VALIDATION,
      KSM_AUTO = KSM_MAXIMIZE_POWER
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and these clarifications!

Regarding the `train_test_ratio`, it seems like this method is very sensitive to the provided ratio. In fact, very rarely the numbers will work perfectly for it to work. Do you agree that this would be a more reliable solution: 

`num_training_samples = int(m_num_samples * train_test_ratio / (train_test_ratio + 1)); num_testing_samples  = m_num_samples -
 num_training_samples`

Thanks for commenting on the other issues.

Comment: To clarify further, I'm trying to run MMD for many sample sets which vary in size. I'd like to set the desired value for ``train_test_ratio`` once and use it for all tests for consistency. With the current scheme, it seems like it would not work. Any advice?

Additionally, how does it work if I'm comparing samples of different size (unlike the example in my code)? How do these formulas change in such cases?

Comment: Two more observations: 1) if I replace QuadraticTimeMMD with LinearTimeMMD, all ratios work fine, e.g, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, etc.; 2) I tried to run QuadraticTimeMMD test with ratio=3; according to your formulas, it should work perfectly, but I still get an error. if you can't reproduce it, I will be happy to share my code.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitry. It looks like you've found a bug. I was able to reproduce this locally. The issue is that the number of samples is not being set properly once the training phase is over. So, in the testing phase (during `compute_statistic` that follows after `select_kernel`), it still expects the same number of samples from the training-mode settings. Luckily, for 50-50 split, these numbers are the same, therefore we don't see this issue. I'll merge a fix for this soon.

Comment: We support using two different number of samples from the distributions. The formula I shared applies to each of these numbers. So, let's say, you have `num_samples_from_p` = 200 and `num_samples_from_q` = 300 and your `train_test_ratio` is 4. So, in training phase, it's gonna use 160 samples from the first distribution and 240 samples from the second distribution, and so on, for testing phase (at least that's how it should behave, once I fix the bug) :)

Comment: Thank you for checking on this issue and letting me know. I'm looking forward to using the code after the fix. Will you be so kind to post a note here when the updated code is available?

Thanks!

Comment: We just merged the fix. Please check out the develop branch. Let me know if any of the issues persist.

Comment: My testing confirms that the latest code does not have this issue. It looks like the patch in: `https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/pull/4134` solved the problem. Thanks for looking at it and fixing it promptly.